# 'StandaloneHTMLBuilder' object has no attribute 'warn'

Tags: python, logging, python-sphinx

I created a small extention for sphinx and would like to display warnings when something is wrong in the directive/role. inspired by some already existing extentions from the sphinx-contrib organization, I used the following:

```py
try:
    font, glyph = get_glyph(node["icon"])
except ValueError as e:
    self.builder.warn(str(e))
    raise nodes.SkipNode
```

when I actually bumped into an error I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'StandaloneHTMLBuilder' object has no attribute 'warn'

Looking on the web, it seems that this attribute has been deprecated. How should I display logging message now ?

**env**
Sphinx >= 4.3.2

Comment: I think you should use https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn). I needed to use the Sphinx logger:

which slighly transform my code into:

```py
from sphinx.util import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    font, glyph = get_glyph(node["icon"])
except ValueError as e:
    logger.warning(str(e), location=node)
    raise nodes.SkipNode
```